# QNX Slogger2 Vs Syslog

Tags: syslog, qnx, systemd-journald

What is the difference between [Slogger2](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/index.html#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.utilities/topic/s/slogger2.html) (System Logger) and Linux based [syslog](https://linux.die.net/man/2/syslog)?

I understand the [difference between journald and syslog](https://www.loggly.com/blog/why-journald/). Slogger2 also gives a way to redirect syslog messages to slogger2.

Is it QNX's version of syslog as it deals with palin text files? Does
Does it also uses [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) like tool to handle file size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`slogger2` (and its predecessor `slogger`) provide a low-latency in-memory log system.   slogger2 is closer conceptually to the Linux kernel log service (eg. `slog2f()` is approximately equivalent to `printk()`), but runs as a user-space daemon independent of the kernel as QNX uses a microkernel architecture.

Like the Linux kernel log, `slogger2` does not write messages to disk by itself; if you want to store messages in a file, you are required to run another process to manage that (ie. `slog2info` is analogous to `klogd`).   It is possible to route syslog into slogger2, to have a single source of message traffic; it is also possible to route slogger2 to syslog, to leverage syslogd's better tools for writing files to disk.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is meant by in-memory log system?

Comment: A solution for managing log message traffic that operates entirely in RAM, so no potentially slow blocking operations are required.   This offers a guarantee that log message writers will not be held up for more than a known latency bound.